# Is there a plugin to get jQuery.ajax to submit multipart/form-data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need this so I can submit a subset of form controls that contain non-ASCII text.

The solution with an iframe element won't work for me because it submits the entire form; I only want to submit a subset of the controls.

I know that I can build a multipart/form-data string myself, but it seems that this must have been done before...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using jQuery and the Form plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api

You can use the `fieldSerialize()` method to submit only a subset of the form and `iframe:true` option to make it work with submitting files, etc.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: That doesn't work; I checked that option already. The Form plugin relies on the browser to construct the form data from a newly generated iframe; it doesn't use fieldSerialize.

But the same technique would be feasible: construct a new iframe with just the fields I want to post. Although just constructing the form-data by hand is probably easier since I don't need file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  As of version 3.02 (which came out early 2012), the  [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) plugin now handles ajax file submits much more friendlierly.  Check it.